# Sudo not asking for password with default sudoers config

Tags: debian, sudo

How do I force to enter the userpassword when executing something with sudo? Right now I have two debian10 systems (one fresh and clean, the other one is by aws) and one raspberry running, and all those have exactly the same sudoers configuration without the
`NOPASSWD:ALL`.
It looks like this on all sudoers configs:

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So why does the fresh clean debian asks me for a password on sudo, and the one by aws / rasperry dont? Is there another config file hidden somewhere? And how do I force the aws system to ask for a userpassword on sudo?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I found a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` called `90-cloud-init-users` and it contains `admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` which is why I didnt get asked for a password.